# Is there a way to mock Kentico providers and types that have been generated for an mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, kentico

I'm starting out in my Kentico developer journey and creating an MVC site.
I wish to write unit tests against my Builder classes but they rely upon auto-generated provider classes that come out of Kentico.
It seems as if the Kentico.Libraries.Tests package will not work with auto-generated provider classes or types. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I'm following the example shown here : https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/writing-automated-tests/faking-info-and-provider-objects-in-unit-tests

But not getting very far...due to an exception, that is causing me some confusion.
The code :

```
Fake<HomePage,HomePageProvider>();
```

throws an exception of:

```
The type 'CMS.DocumentEngine.Types.HomePage' cannot be used as type 
parameter 'TInfo' in the generic type or method 
'AutomatedTestsWithData.Fake<TInfo, TProvider>(TProvider, bool)'. 

There is no implicit reference conversion from 
'CMS.DocumentEngine.Types.HomePage' 
to 
'CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoBase<CMS.DocumentEngine.Types.HomePage>'.
```

The HomePage Class looks like:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//
//     This code was generated by code generator tool.
//
//     To customize the code use your own partial class. For more info about how to use and customize
//     the generated code see the documentation at http://docs.kentico.com.
//
// </auto-generated>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using CMS;
using CMS.Base;
using CMS.Helpers;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.DocumentEngine.Types;
using CMS.DocumentEngine;

[assembly: RegisterDocumentType(HomePage.CLASS_NAME, typeof(HomePage))]

namespace CMS.DocumentEngine.Types
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a content item of type HomePage.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class HomePage : TreeNode
    {
        #region "Constants and variables"

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the data class.
        /// </summary>
        public const string CLASS_NAME = "HomePage";


        /// <summary>
        /// The instance of the class that provides extended API for working with HomePage fields.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly HomePageFields mFields;

        #endregion


        #region "Properties"

        /// <summary>
        /// HomePageID.
        /// </summary>
        [DatabaseIDField]
        public int HomePageID
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetInteger(GetValue("HomePageID"), 0);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue("HomePageID", value);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This heading shown in the breadcrumb.
        /// </summary>
        [DatabaseField]
        public string PageHeading
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("PageHeading"), @"");
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue("PageHeading", value);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Header Image.
        /// </summary>
        [DatabaseField]
        public string HeaderImage
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("HeaderImage"), @"");
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue("HeaderImage", value);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Header Image Alt Text.
        /// </summary>
        [DatabaseField]
        public string HeaderImageAltText
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("HeaderImageAltText"), @"");
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue("HeaderImageAltText", value);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Title.
        /// </summary>
        [DatabaseField]
        public string HeaderTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("HeaderTitle"), @"");
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue("HeaderTitle", value);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an object that provides extended API for working with HomePage fields.
        /// </summary>
        [RegisterProperty]
        public HomePageFields Fields
        {
            get
            {
                return mFields;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Provides extended API for working with HomePage fields.
        /// </summary>
        [RegisterAllProperties]
        public partial class HomePageFields : AbstractHierarchicalObject<HomePageFields>
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The content item of type HomePage that is a target of the extended API.
            /// </summary>
            private readonly HomePage mInstance;


            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HomePageFields" /> class with the specified content item of type HomePage.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="instance">The content item of type HomePage that is a target of the extended API.</param>
            public HomePageFields(HomePage instance)
            {
                mInstance = instance;
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// HomePageID.
            /// </summary>
            public int ID
            {
                get
                {
                    return mInstance.HomePageID;
                }
                set
                {
                    mInstance.HomePageID = value;
                }
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// This heading shown in the breadcrumb.
            /// </summary>
            public string PageHeading
            {
                get
                {
                    return mInstance.PageHeading;
                }
                set
                {
                    mInstance.PageHeading = value;
                }
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Header Image.
            /// </summary>
            public string HeaderImage
            {
                get
                {
                    return mInstance.HeaderImage;
                }
                set
                {
                    mInstance.HeaderImage = value;
                }
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Header Image Alt Text.
            /// </summary>
            public string HeaderImageAltText
            {
                get
                {
                    return mInstance.HeaderImageAltText;
                }
                set
                {
                    mInstance.HeaderImageAltText = value;
                }
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Title.
            /// </summary>
            public string HeaderTitle
            {
                get
                {
                    return mInstance.HeaderTitle;
                }
                set
                {
                    mInstance.HeaderTitle = value;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion


        #region "Constructors"

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HomePage" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        public HomePage() : base(CLASS_NAME)
        {
            mFields = new HomePageFields(this);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might want to look at how they did the tests for the MVC project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Kentico/Mvc/blob/master/test/DancingGoat.Tests/Unit/ArticleControllerTests.cs) and see if it helps.

Comment: for others that find this question & if you dont want to look at the github TLDR:
use the Kentico.Libraries.Tests nuget, make your test class extend from 'UnitTests'. 
then use :
`Fake().DocumentType<Model>(Model.CLASS_NAME);`

Comment: In addition to the comment from @Timtek - You'll need to call UnitTests.UnitTestsSetUp();   This helps to setup the Kentico initialization properties when you're running unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to play with [PageInfo](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_0/api/html/T_CMS_DocumentEngine_PageInfo.htm) and [PageInfoProvider](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/10_0/api/html/T_CMS_DocumentEngine_PageInfoProvider.htm) classes.

Comment: PageInfoProvider doesn't work for ContentOnly pages (Kentico 9 through 11)